# Combining/concatenating the results of a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm using Oracle SQL to pull a list of customers and their delivery days into Excel. The format of the data is such that every delivery day has its own record, so if customer 10001 gets deliveries on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, I'll get three records returned (in this case: 2, 4, 6 since our weeks start on Sundays).

I've used CASE to convert these into initials (M, W, F), but there are obviously still three records.

I initially thought this was a concatenation problem (I am VERY new to SQL code) so I tried the standard double pipes (||), but this is not the same kind of concatenation action (I've learned the double pipes are for concatenating different fields).

This is where my code is currently sitting:

```
SELECT 
TRIPS.CUSTOMER_NO||TRIPS.CUSTOMER_NAME as CUSTOMER, 
CASE
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 1 THEN 'U'
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 2 THEN 'M'
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 3 THEN 'T'
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 4 THEN 'W'
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 5 THEN 'R'
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 6 THEN 'F'
WHEN TRIPS.DAY_NO= 7 THEN 'S'
ELSE '0'
END AS DAYS
FROM DB.TRIPs
```

What I would like at the end is for each customer to return a single record, with the delivery days concatenated (in this case, to MWF).   There are many thousands of customers and I'm currently having to accomplish this using a pivot table in a very clunky way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `LISTAGG()`:

```
SELECT t.CUSTOMER_NO || t.CUSTOMER_NAME as CUSTOMER, 
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN t.DAY_NO = 1 THEN 'U'
                    WHEN t.DAY_NO = 2 THEN 'M'
                    WHEN t.DAY_NO = 3 THEN 'T'
                    WHEN t.DAY_NO = 4 THEN 'W'
                    WHEN t.DAY_NO = 5 THEN 'R'
                    WHEN t.DAY_NO = 6 THEN 'F'
                    WHEN t.DAY_NO = 7 THEN 'S'
                    ELSE '0'
               END) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.DAY_NO) as days
FROM DB.TRIPs t
GROUP BY t.CUSTOMER_NO || t.CUSTOMER_NAME
```

Comment: Hmm.  That's generating an ORA 00905 missing keyword error.